# Website is not responsive from templated.co

Tags: html, css, templates, responsive-design

I am very new to HTML and i am trying to make my website responsive. I chose [this](https://templated.co/fetchingly) template from templated.co . I made some changes and gave credits to them for design. And after everything when i check for responsiveness its not responsive in mobiles/ipad. We can download the code directly from templated.co . Can any one please help me make my website responsive?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the template does not come with media queries (specifications in the CSS that allows content to adapt to screen resolution). You'll need to code those yourself, as they are specific to the CSS used. Try searching for media query tutorials on youtube if you're unsure of how to code them. Also, check out [this](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2013/06/responsive-media-queries-css.html) template. (You don't need to use all of the queries, but the more you use, the more flexible your site will be)

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
    ul li {
        padding-left: 30px;
        background: blue;
    }

    }
```

An example query would look like this. Max and min define the boundaries of how the site will change under restriction, and are always in pixels. This is saying that *ul* and *li* will have 30px padding and a blue background if the screen-size pixel conditions are met. For every phone/tablet size, you need a new media query with new specifications.